# How to scale Cocos2d app to iPhone 5 screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Cocos3d v1.01 app and I am currently making it try to fit the iPhone 5 full screen.

By simply stretching the background is enough for most screens as it is just a pattern that fills the screen and no need to change any UI parts, however on just one of the screens I am struggling to change.

This is the code part I believe to set the background for that;

```
-(void)animations
{

    AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];


        NSMutableArray *bodyanimframeBuddyBack =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(int j = 1;j<=4;++j)
        {

            [bodyanimframeBuddyBack addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"shark_sea_waves5%d.png",j]]];

        }

        CCAnimation *BuddyAnimBack = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:bodyanimframeBuddyBack delay:0.3f];
        self.backgroundAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:BuddyAnimBack restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

        CCSprite  *bg=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"shark_sea_waves51.png"];

        bg.position=ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        [self addChild:bg];
        [bg runAction:backgroundAction];
```

Is there a way of adjusting that ? I am guessing it is the bg.position part that would need changing to tell it whether it is iPhone5 or not?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: What exactly is it doing that you would like to fix?

Comment: It is centered in the screen on iPhone 5 but i want that to be stretched as well, I have the usual @2x files so the splash screen and main menu is fine on iPhone 5 it is just this screen it is an animation it is portrait size I just want it to fill the entire iPhone 5 screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bg.scaleX = size.width / bg.contentSize.width;
```

This will stretch the bg width to match the screen width.

Comment: That just makes it in the bottom left corner only?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user1695971 The only thing the above does, is adjust the width of the bg sprite, to match the width of the screen.

Comment: If I remove
bg.position=ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);

and replace it with your 
bg.scaleX = size.width / bg.contentSize.width;

Then it just makes the background image a square in the bottom left corner and the rest is black.

If I keep both then it just goes back to being bars top and bottom on the iPhone :(

Comment: @user1695971 Who told you to remove the positioning code? If you don't position it, of course it will be in the lower left corner.

Comment: @user1695971 Ah so you need to adjust the height as well?

Comment: The height only in this app no worries about width :)

Comment: @user1695971 I was imagining it in landscape mode, but it sounds like you are in portrait mode. So just add another line for height `bg.scaleY = size.height / bg.contentSize.height;`

Comment: You sir, are a genius! It works perfectly thank you so much for your time and help today! I have marked the answer by you thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you place seperate background for iPhone5..just like you did for iPad.

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)

#define TEX_MM_BG   (IS_IPHONE5) ? ( @"shark_sea_waves51-whd.png") : ( @"shark_sea_waves51.png")


-(void)setupBackground
{
    CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:TEX_MM_BG];
    bg.position  = ccp(mS.width*0.5f, mS.height*0.5f);
    [self addChild:bg z:-3 tag:kTagBackground];
}
```

//Also put these image in hard disk.

```
shark_sea_waves51.png       //480x320
shark_sea_waves51-hd.png    //960x640
shark_sea_waves51-whd.png   //1136x640
shark_sea_waves51-ipad.png  //1024x768
shark_sea_waves51-ipadhd.png //2048x1536
```